# How to reverse an array using pointers in c

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to print the reverse of an array using pointers eg. input is 4 8 15 7, I want to print 7 15 8 4.

When I run it, it reverses some numbers but not all? Sometimes it doesn't reverse any numbers. I am very confused.

I need it to work for an unknown number of elements in the array, which is why I used the while loops in 'readIntoArray' and 'printArray'. I'm really just struggling with 'reverseArray' and 'swap'.

```
void reverseArray(double numbers[], int size);
void printArray(double numbers[], int size);
int readIntoArray(double numbers[]);
void swap(double *a, double *b);

int main(void) {
    double numbers[MAX_SIZE];
    int size = readIntoArray(numbers);
    reverseArray(numbers, size);
    printArray(numbers, size);
    return 0;
}

int readIntoArray(double numbers[]) {
    double in;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < MAX_SIZE && scanf("%lf", &in) != 0) {
        numbers[i] = in;
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}

void reverseArray(double numbers[], int size){
    int x = 0;
    double *a = &numbers[x];
    double *b = &numbers[size - x];
    double temp;
    while (x < size){
        swap(a,b);
        x++;
    }
}

void printArray(double numbers[], int size){
    int i = 0;
    while (i<size){
        printf("%lf ", numbers[i]);
        i++;
    }
}

void swap (double *a, double *b){
    int temp;
    temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

How do I make it work? What am I missing?

Comment: Let's see `int temp;` and `double *a, double *b` -- something is very wrong here. (one of these things is not like the other, one of the things just doesn't belong... sung to Sesame Street Tune...) (hint: `int` 4-bytes, `double` 8-bytes so what is going into `temp = *a;`?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of glaring issues, but the primary problem is your use of differing type sizes in `swap`, e.g.

```
void swap (double *a, double *b){
    int temp;
    temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

You are providing type `double` as a parameter (generally an 8-byte value), but then using `int temp;` (generally a 4-byte value) as your temporary pointer. So even if you have everything else correct, you are only storing the first 4-bytes of `*a` in `temp`.

Next, you will end up swapping twice (ending up back where you started) if you reverse over the full range `0 < size`. Instead, you on want to swap each end element over the range `0 < size / 2`. For example:

```
void reverseArray(double numbers[], size_t size){
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size / 2; i++)
        swap (&numbers[i], &numbers[size - i - 1]);
}
```

(**note:** counters should generally be `size_t` instead of `int` (you cannot have a negative line count))

Further, you need to fix you `scanf` validation. `scanf() != 0` allows `scanf() = EOF`  to test `TRUE` which is obviously not what you want. You validate the return *against the number of conversion specifiers*, e.g.

```
size_t readIntoArray(double numbers[]) {
    double in;
    size_t i = 0;
    while (i < MAX_SIZE && scanf("%lf", &in) == 1) {    /* <== here */
        numbers[i] = in;
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Putting it altogether, and refactoring your code to avoid the need for function prototypes, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_SIZE  128

size_t readIntoArray(double numbers[]) {
    double in;
    size_t i = 0;
    while (i < MAX_SIZE && scanf("%lf", &in) == 1) {
        numbers[i] = in;
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}

void swap (double *a, double *b){
    double temp;
    temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

void reverseArray(double numbers[], size_t size){
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size / 2; i++)
        swap (&numbers[i], &numbers[size - i - 1]);
}

void printArray(double numbers[], size_t size){
    int i = 0;
    while (size--)
        printf("%g ", numbers[i++]);
    putchar ('\n');
}

int main(void) {

    double numbers[MAX_SIZE] = { 0 };
    size_t size = readIntoArray(numbers);
    reverseArray (numbers, size);
    printArray (numbers, size);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ echo "4 8 15 7" | ./bin/revarrswap
7 15 8 4
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
double *a = &numbers[x];
double *b = &numbers[size - x];
double temp;
while (x < size){
    swap(a,b);
    x++;
}
```

Never changes the values of a and b. Even though you are modifying x, you have already assigned the addresses of the first and one-after-the-last elements to these variables and proceed swapping them for all values of x.

A somewhat better implementation which should achieve what you intended:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i != size/2; i++) {
    swap(&numbers[i], &numbers[size-i-1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(double *a, double *b){
    int temp;
    temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

void reverse(double numbers[], int size) {
    int half = size / 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < half; i++) {
        swap(numbers[i], numbers[size-1-i]);
    }
}

int main() {
    double ns[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};

    reverse(ns, 5);

    for (int i=0; i<5;i++) {
        printf("%d\n", ns[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `reverseArray()` function:

```
void reverseArray(double numbers[], int size){
    int x = 0;
    double *a = &numbers[x];
    double *b = &numbers[size - x];
    double temp;
    while (x < size){
        swap(a,b);
        x++;
    }
}
```

First of all, here

```
double *b = &numbers[size - x];
```

your code is accessing array beyond its size. If the size of array is, lets say, `10` then the valid indexes of array are from `0` to `9` and `size - x` will give you `10` because at this point the value of `x` is `0`. Accessing array beyond its size is [**undefined behavior**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

In `reverseArray()` function, you are assigning the address of specific elements of `numbers` array to the pointers `a` and `b` and not changing them within the `while` loop. In every iteration of loop the `swap()` function end up swapping the value of same two pointers and out of those two pointers, one is pointing beyond array. Moreover, the loop is iterating `size` times. Instead, it should iterate only for `size / 2` times.

The `reverseArray()` should be like this:

```
void reverseArray(double numbers[], int size){
    int x = 0;
    while (x < size / 2){
        swap(&numbers[x], &numbers[(size - 1) - x]);
        x++;
    }
}
```

There are other problems in the code like use of `temp` variable of type `int` in `swap()` function to swap `double` type values, not handling `scanf()` return appropriately etc. which has been very well explained by @David C. Rankin in his post. It doesn't make any sense to reiterate them.