# Reverse an array in C, and troubleshooting in main

Tags: arrays, c

im actually learning C proigramming, and in an exercise i need to reverse an array using a pointer. i think my logic is correct, but im having trouble writing my main, and testing it.

with this exact code i have a implicit declaration of a function, but i dont understand where it comes from.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void    ft_rev_int_tab(*tab, int size)
{
    int temp; // variable pour swap
    int decrem = size - 1; //si tab[5],derniere valeur = 4
    int i = 0; // initialisation a 0 pour incrémentation
    
    while(i <= (size / 2)) // swap jusqu'a la moitié
    {
        tab[i] = temp;
        tab[size - 1] = temp; // swap de deux valeurs
        i++; // incrementation pour passer a l'index suivant
        decrem--; //decrementation pour passer a l'index précedent
    }
}
int main(void)
{
    int tab[5] = {0,1,2,3,4};
    ft_rev_int_tab(tab, 5);
}
```

Comment: What is the type of the pointer `tab`? You just wrote `*tab` without any type, it is not compilable.

Comment: To what does tab point?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reverse an array using pointers in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55272725/how-to-reverse-an-array-using-pointers-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

You do not have a type for the first argument of the function.

```c
void    ft_rev_int_tab(*tab, int size)
```

Notice how `*tab`, doesn't have a type in front of it like `int size`.

Change it to:

```c
void ft_rev_int_tab(int *tab, int size)
```

And that should resolve the issue.

When you encounter problems like this, try to go over your code, to see what is missing. Does everything have a type? Do I have all my brackets? With practice, you will develop checklists like that for yourself.

Comment: I am massively blind, thank you ! , i should have seen this earlier

Answer (score 1):

```
void    ft_rev_int_tab(*tab, int size)
```

Two errors:

1. `tab` does not have type
2. `size` should have `size_t` type

It is very convenient if the function returns the reference to the reversed array

It has to be :

```
int *ft_rev_int_tab(int *tab, size_t size)
```

This code is also invalid.

```
    while(i <= (size / 2)) // swap jusqu'a la moitié
    {
        tab[i] = temp;
        tab[size - 1] = temp; // swap de deux valeurs
        i++; // incrementation pour passer a l'index suivant
        decrem--; //decrementation pour passer a l'index précedent
    }
```

I cant even think what is the idea of this code

It has to be:

```
int *ft_rev_int_tab(int *tab, size_t size)
{
    int temp; // variable pour swap
    size_t i = 0; // initialisation a 0 pour incrémentation
    
    while(i <= (size / 2)) 
    {
        temp = tab[i];
        tab[i] = tab[size - 1 - i];
        tab[size - 1 - i] = temp;
        i++;
    }
    return tab;
}
```

Comment: Do you know why size_t is preferable here ? im tinkering in debug mode, and a simple int size seems to work, im curious about that

Comment: Return from a void function???

Comment: @Neptune because it is the type for **sizes**

Comment: @Gearoid if you read my answer you would see that is a copy-paste error.